#  How to draw filled polygon?

Tags: android

How to draw filled polygon in Android ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to set the paint object to FILL

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

Then you can draw whatever you want, and it will be filled.

```
canvas.drawCircle(20, 20, 15, paint);
canvas.drawRectangle(60, 20, 15, paint);
```

etc.

For more complex shapes you need to use the [PATH object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html).

Comment: is it possible to fill this polygon with icons(Marker)? with some padding and specified space between the icons?

Answer (score 120):

Android does not have a handy `drawPolygon(x_array, y_array, numberofpoints)` action like Java. You have to walk through making a `Path` object point by point. For example, to make a filled trapezoid shape for a 3D dungeon wall, you could put all your points in x and y arrays then code as follows:

```
Paint wallpaint = new Paint();
wallpaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
wallpaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

Path wallpath = new Path();
wallpath.reset(); // only needed when reusing this path for a new build
wallpath.moveTo(x[0], y[0]); // used for first point
wallpath.lineTo(x[1], y[1]);
wallpath.lineTo(x[2], y[2]);
wallpath.lineTo(x[3], y[3]);
wallpath.lineTo(x[0], y[0]); // there is a setLastPoint action but i found it not to work as expected

canvas.drawPath(wallpath, wallpaint);
```

To add a constant linear gradient for some depth, you could code as follows. Note y[0] is used twice to keep the gradient horizontal:

```
 wallPaint.reset(); // precaution when resusing Paint object, here shader replaces solid GRAY anyway
 wallPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(x[0], y[0], x[1], y[0], Color.GRAY, Color.DKGRAY,TileMode.CLAMP)); 

 canvas.drawPath(wallpath, wallpaint);
```

Refer to [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html), [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) documentation for more options, such as array defined gradients, adding arcs, and laying a Bitmap over your polygon.

Comment: Instead of using `Path.lineTo(x0, y0)` you can simply call `Path.close()` to automatically add the closing line segment.

Answer (score 11):

I like to do it in three steps...

**Step 1. Create a pointy class ;-)**

```
/**
 * Simple point
 */
private class Point {

    public float x = 0;
    public float y = 0;

    public Point(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**Step 2. Add a method/function for drawing**

```
/**
 * Draw polygon
 *
 * @param canvas The canvas to draw on
 * @param color  Integer representing a fill color (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)
 * @param points Polygon corner points
 */
private void drawPoly(Canvas canvas, int color, Point[] points) {
    // line at minimum...
    if (points.length < 2) {
        return;
    }

    // paint
    Paint polyPaint = new Paint();
    polyPaint.setColor(color);
    polyPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    // path
    Path polyPath = new Path();
    polyPath.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    int i, len;
    len = points.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        polyPath.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
    polyPath.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);

    // draw
    canvas.drawPath(polyPath, polyPaint);
}
```

**Step 3. Draw**

```
    drawPoly(canvas, 0xFF5555ee,
            new Point[]{
                new Point(10, 10),
                new Point(15, 10),
                new Point(15, 20)
            });
```

Yes, you could probably do it more efficiently, but probably not much more readable :-).

Comment: This code has some serious issues: first there are already two `Point` and `PointF` classes in Android so you really don't need to reinvent your own. Second you really want to avoid allocating objects in your View.draw() methods and the sample you provided does tons of allocations for a single draw.

Comment: That depends how many rectangles you want to draw. But I agree this is not the most efficient way to do it. But being efficient usually means making the code less usable or readable or both.

Answer (score 5):

**Draw Polygon with x sides and custom radius:**

```
private void drawPolygon(Canvas mCanvas, float x, float y, float radius, float sides, float startAngle, boolean anticlockwise, Paint paint) {

    if (sides < 3) { return; }

    float a = ((float) Math.PI *2) / sides * (anticlockwise ? -1 : 1);
    mCanvas.save();
    mCanvas.translate(x, y);
    mCanvas.rotate(startAngle);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(radius, 0);
    for(int i = 1; i < sides; i++) {
        path.lineTo(radius * (float) Math.cos(a * i), radius * (float) Math.sin(a * i));
    }
    path.close();
    mCanvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    mCanvas.restore();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

BTW - I discovered that once you begin creating your path, any moveTo commands within the path will mean that the shape is left unfilled.

It makes sense when you think about it, that Android/Java would leave the shape unfilled as the moveTo would represent a break in the polygon.

However I've seen some tutorials like this [How to draw a filled triangle in android canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501126/how-to-draw-a-filled-triangle-in-android-canvas)

which have moveTo's after each lineTo. Even though this may result in an unbroken polygon, Android assumes that a moveTo represents a break in the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but a trick for anyone who finds this. If you include a font with the desired polygon as a glyph you can use the drawText function to draw your polygon.

The downside is you have to know ahead of time what shapes you'll need. The upside it is if you do know ahead of time you can include a nice shape library. This code assumes you have a font called shapes in your assets/fonts folder of your project.

```
            TypeFace shapesTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/shapes.ttf");
            Paint stopSignPaint = new Paint();
            stopSignPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            //set anti-aliasing so it looks nice
            stopSignPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            stopSignPaint.setTextSize(200);
            stopSignPaint.setTypeface(shapesTypeFace);

            //will show up as a box or question mark since 
            //the current display font doesn't have this glyph. 
            //open the shapes font in a tool like Character Map 
            //to copy and paste the glyph into your IDE
            //saving it as a variable makes it much easier to work with
            String hexagonGlyph = ""
            String triangleGlyph = ""


            ....whatever code you got...


            //arguments: text, x coordinate, y coordinate, paint
             canvas.drawText(hexagonGlyph, 200, 100, stopSignPaint);

            //make it into a go sign
            stopSignPaint.setColor(Color.Green);
             canvas.drawText(hexagonGlyph, 200, 100, stopSignPaint);


            //make a tiny one
            stopSignPaint.setTextSize(20);
            stopSignPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
             canvas.drawText(hexagonGlyph, 200, 100, stopSignPaint);


             //make a triangle
             canvas.drawText(triangleGlyph, 200, 100, stopSignPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

This class can be used to draw any kind of polygons. Just call `drawPolygonPath()` in onDraw() method.

```
class PolygonView : View {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        init()
    }

    private lateinit var paint: Paint

    private fun init() {
        paint = Paint().apply {
            color = Color.RED
            isAntiAlias = true
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            strokeWidth = 10f
        }
    }


    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(drawPolygonPath(8, 150f), paint)
        canvas.drawPath(drawPolygonPath(5, 120f), paint)

    }

    /**
     * @param sides number of polygon sides
     * @param radius side length.
     * @param cx drawing x start point.
     * @param cy drawing y start point.
     * */
    private fun drawPolygonPath(
        sides: Int,
        radius: Float,
        cx: Float = radius,
        cy: Float = radius
    ): Path {
        val path = Path()
        val x0 = cx + (radius * cos(0.0).toFloat())
        val y0 = cy + (radius * sin(0.0).toFloat())
        //2.0 * Math.PI = 2π, which means one circle(360)
        //The polygon total angles of the sides must equal 360 degree.
        val angle = 2 * Math.PI / sides

        path.moveTo(x0, y0)

        for (s in 1 until sides) {

            path.lineTo(
                cx + (radius * cos(angle * s)).toFloat(),
                cy + (radius * sin(angle * s)).toFloat()
            )
        }

        path.close()

        return path
    }
}
```