# Android Drawing on Canvas

Tags: android, canvas

[image]

I have a canvas on which I'm drawing this figure, using array of points. How to fill it with a particular color?

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    RectF oval = new RectF(90, 100, 200, 300);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

    //  canvas.drawRect(oval, paint);

    //canvas.drawArc(oval, 30f, 100f, true, paint);

    float [] pts = {0,200,
                    120,140,120,140,
                    180,20,180,20,
                    260,100,260,100,
                    350,20,350,20,
                    410,140,410,140,
                    530,200,530,200,
                    410,260,410,260,
                    350,380,350,380,
                    260,300,260,300,
                    180,380,180,380,
                    120,260,120,260,
                    0,200
     };

    //canvas.drawPoints(pts, paint);
    canvas.drawLines(pts, paint);

    //RectF tail = new RectF(0f, 50f, 200f,100f);   
    //canvas.drawArc(tail, 0f, 50f, true, paint);

    //canvas.drawRoundRect(oval, 20f, 20f, paint);

    invalidate();

}
```

So basically what I want to do is to just fill the color along these points which are present in array. Any help on this??

Comment: try applying style to `Paint`... `paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);`

Comment: sorry to say this,but its not working.Any other suggestion??

Comment: what these points represents? rectangle or triangle or something like that? can you show an image how does it look likes after drawing?

Comment: I've updated my ques,you can see the image above.Thanx

Comment: An equal problem was already [solved][1] previously by Pavel.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501126/how-to-draw-a-filled-triangle-in-android-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to build a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and use canvas.drawPath.