# Custom Button painting on Android

Tags: java, android, button, android-custom-view

## Goal

My goal is to edit a Button so that it's shape is a little triangle with the shape of *<* and *>*.

```
Shape 1         Shape 2

    /|          |\
   / |          | \
  /  |          |  \
 /   |          |   \
/    |          |    \
\    |          |    /
 \   |          |   /
  \  |          |  /
   \ |          | /
    \|          |/
```

## What I know

I never edited the painting process of a `Button`, so I am kind of lost. I have used `Canvas` and done some games by overwriting painting functions in Java, however, it's not clear for me how to proceed to achieve this in Android. I know I wil have to do the following things:

1. Create a class that extends `Button`
2. Edit the *painting*/*drawing* of it so that it has the shape I want
3. Create an instace of it and add it to my layout on runtime

## Question

1. What functions do I have to overwrite to do this?
2. Will the highligting when clicked work well or do I have to fix that too?
3. Can the click highlight be turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just use something like the answer in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501126/how-to-draw-a-filled-triangle-in-android-canvas). Since my shape is a triangle, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageButton and set the image that you want to set there.

Comment: I don't use images.