# Clickable polygon Android

Tags: android, polygon, touch-event

With [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047573/how-to-draw-filled-polygon) question I somwhat understood how to draw a polygon in Android, but is there any way to make this click(touch)able?

Requirements:

I'm going to have multiple polygons in one view: each polygon must have it's own unique ontouchevent.

I need a lot of the functionality of a polygon, so they can't be replaced by images.

Answer (score 0):

if this polygon has solid color, you can:

1. assign a bitmap to the custom view canvas.
2. implement ontouch in the custom view
3. register the x,y user touched in the ontouch method
4. get the pixel color in [x,y] from the custom view bitmap.
5. check if the color of the pixel that was clicked is the color of the polygon.

Comment: clever workaround; yes it shall have a solid color, but no; because there's going to be multible polygons with the same color. Thanks Anyway!

Comment: several polygon on the same custom view or each polygon could be its own custom view?