# How to fill a polygon in java?

Tags: java, graphics

I have one little problem.. I am actually doing a program in java (it's a GUI).
There is one class named Map that in which I creat a map..(or atleast I am trying).The constructor initializes the map and it gives back an Area and I paint it in the View class. I tried the classical way to do it with g2.fillPolygon(x[],y[],n) but it does not works. Here is the source code:

```
public class Map{
    Area area;
    //...
    public Map(){
        this.area=new Area(new Polygon(
                arrayX(),//ArrayY() and arrayX() are methods that generate     arrays with random numbers
                arrayY(),
                MAX
                ));
   }

//...stuff
}
```

Here is the View class:

```
public class View extends JComponent{
    Map map=new Map();

//...stuff

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
//.......

    g2.draw(map.area);//this draws the normal polygon NOT filled
    g2.fillPolygon(map.ArrayX,map.arrayY,map.MAX);//this might fill the polygon but it does noot
    g2.fillPolygon(map.area);//this does not work (ofcourse) because it wants a Polygon type parameter. I tried to cast it but it still does not work.
}
}
```

What shall I do in this case? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for my grammar. I wrote it quickly.

Comment: Side note: don't name your class/type with names which are already used by Java, like `Map` `List` `Set` `Object` `Character`.

Comment: I believe you need a Paint object passed to the fillPolygon method.  And that paint object would have fill attributes and color etc.

Comment: This might help:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047573/how-to-draw-filled-polygon

Comment: Make an actual `Polygon` and pass that?

Comment: @Pshemo I know it! in fact it does not names like that!! It is in Italian but I changed it to English to post it here :)

Comment: `Graphics2D#fill`, just like you used `draw`, but with `fill`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are a genius!!!!! thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the [`Graphics2D#draw(Shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)) method, there is a [`Graphics2D#fill(shape)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill(java.awt.Shape)) method.

```
g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
g2.fill(map.area);
g2.setColor(Color.RED);
g2.draw(map.area);
```

You might like to have a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details