# How to think about this custom view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm trying to do the gradient view cutted at bottom of this image

[image]

What tools should I use to build that custom rectangle with the last part slided ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047573/how-to-draw-filled-polygon

Comment: I think it would be easier to use a background image for your container